# Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: jquery

Trying to use On screen keyboard but I am receiving an error in this code:

```
if ($key.hasClass('osk-backspace')) {
    inputValue = $input.val();
    $input.val(inputValue.substr(0, inputValue.length - 1));
    $input.trigger('keyup');
    return false;
}
```

Error:

> Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Comment: if inputValue may be a null.

Comment: this page: https://trinkgutdatteln.de/contactmanager/

Comment: Kruchko its hard to find some code on the page so share your html part also

Comment: there is jquery.js is included 3 times. Can this be a reason of the error?